# git logs not matching when setting --work-tree with push-to-deploy post-receive hook

Tags: git, git-post-receive, git-bare

I have setup push-to-deploy with my production server by setting up a `--bare` directory at `/home/ubuntu/push-to-deploy/test.git`, using that as my remote and adding a `hooks/post-receive` inside the `--bare` looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
  if [ "production" == "$branch" -o "master" == "$branch" ]; then

    git --work-tree=/var/www/test/ checkout -f $branch
    sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/test

    echo 'Changes pushed to Amazon EC2 PROD.'
  fi
done
```

This works great when pushing to this new remote from my localhost.  The `post-receive` script executes as it should and the content updates are reflected in the `/var/www/test` directory as they should be.  The only thing is that my `git log` inside `/var/www/test` is not matching my localhost at all.  Is this normal behavior of `--work-tree`?  If so, what can I do to retain this `push-to-deploy` functionality and still have my git log copied over to the production directory as well as the content?

**Also**

When my content copies into the production directory (`/var/www/test`) all the file ownerships are overrode to `ubuntu:ubuntu` which makes the `www-data` not be able to do its thing.  I put a line in my `post-receive` to update the ownership after each receive but is there another way (a better way) to do this?

**UPDATE**

The way to ensure that `www-data` is retained as the group is to set the directory's guid like this:

```
chmod -R g+s /var/www/test
```

This will set it to whatever the current group of the directory is, so if you want it to be `www-data` then make sure you set the group to `www-data` before you issue that command.

Thanks

Comment: `git log --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/push-to-deploy/test.git` should work just fine when executed from `/var/www/test`.

Comment: fatal: unrecognized argument: --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/push-to-deploy/test.git

Comment: Sorry, I meant `git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/push-to-deploy/test.git log`

Comment: also, should I then add an option in the `/var/www/test/.git/config` to change the `git-dir` to `/home/ubuntu/push-to-deploy/test.git` so I don't have to specify that `--git-dir` option for each command like that?

Comment: I propose in my answer to set the environment variable `GIT_DIR`.

Comment: Note that simply splitting up the ref-name with `cut -d/` is not quite right: if there's a ref of the form `refs/tags/master/v2`, for instance, `cut` will extract field 3 which will be `master`.  It's probably fine in this particular case, but in general you should just test `"$ref" == refs/heads/master` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `GIT_DIR` to `/home/ubuntu/push-to-deploy/test.git` and:

- do your `git --work-tree=/var/www/test/ checkout -f $branch`
- or do your `git log` in `/var/www/test/`

In both case, the right index will be taken into account.

---

The [OP sadmicrowave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281488/sadmicrowave) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048155/git-logs-not-matching-when-setting-work-tree-with-push-to-deploy-post-receive#comment35216875_23048260):

> just did a **`chmod -R g+s /var/www/test`** and it is working now.

Comment: that sounds like it would work in this case but what if I had more than one git repo on my production server?

Comment: @sadmicrowave then you need to have some script/wrapper which encapsulate the git commands you want to run while setting the `GIT_DIR` to the right repo.

Comment: any recommendations for the second part of my op?

Comment: nvm - just did a `chmod -R g+s /var/www/test` and it is working now