# Does git allow for "bare" submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-bare

This may be terrible, I am not sure.

Let us say we have a repo "product" with a working directory

```
/product
/product/command.script
/product/config/ (bare git repo)
```

And a repo "config" with a working directory

```
/config
/config/config.json
```

The command.script file has actions to interact with a bare repo. ex. Running command.script BRANCH1 would run the command

```
git show BRANCH1:config.json
```

Is there any way that the "/product/config/" folder can be a submodule of the "product" repo, such that when the "product" repo is cloned the "config" repo will also be cloned

```
git clone --bare [config origin here] config
```

from its origin and when the "product" repo is fetched, the "/product/config" submodule can be fetched

```
git fetch origin '*:*'
```

Or is this something that should be handled through hooks of some sort?

Comment: Allow bare submodules: I don't think so.

Comment: @linquize Why not? It will make a "full" repo backup a much simpler. At least the `--mirror` option is available only in a bare variant, so you have to clone twice: as a bare repository and as not bare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: when the repo "product" is fetched, its index will include a [gitlink (special entry recording the SHA1 of the submodule)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309).

That entry can only be used in a non-bare repo, in order to be expended as a nested (submodule) repo.

That is why the [`git clone` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) mentions:

```
--recursive
--recurse-submodules
```

> After the clone is created, initialize all submodules within, using their default settings. This is equivalent to running `git submodule update --init --recursive` immediately after the clone is finished.
>   **This option is ignored if the cloned repository does not have a worktree/checkout** (i.e. if any of `--no-checkout/-n`, `--bare`, or `--mirror` is given)

---

That means it is best for the `config` repo to be cloned separately (even bare) at the right SHA1 (the one recorded by the gitlink in the first `product` repo), and for the `git show BRANCH1:config.json` to be executed in that other cloned repo ([with `git -C`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115753/6309)).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know they added the -C switch either.  That will be usefull. So hooks would not be a good way to go?

Comment: @TylerClendenin yes, a clone --bare allows for a repo to be push to (you can push to a bare repo). You can then add a post-receive hook to perform any process you want, as I explained yesterday in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25499592/6309.